# Rewrite url which redirects to page on webserver

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to get a page with a query string to redirect to a nicer looking url then get that url and transfer it  back to the original query string but without redirecting (i.e. without changing the url)
At the moment I am getting a redirect loop (for obvious reasons) but I was hoping for a way to stop this.

This is my code in my htaccess file

```
#rewrite search querystring
    #/search/'apartment'/2_bedrooms/price_0-500000/town_W4/development_18,SW5/
        RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)_bedrooms/price_([^/]+)-([^/]+)/town_([^/]+)/development_([^/]+) /search.php?propertytype=$1&bedrooms=$2&minprice=$3&maxprice=$4&location=$5&development=$6 [NC]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} propertytype=([^/]+)&bedrooms=([^/]+)&minprice=([^/]+)&maxprice=([^/]+)&location=([^/]+)&development=([^/]+)
    /search/$1/$2_bedrooms/price_$3-$4/town_$5/development_$6 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /search/%1/%2_bedrooms/price_%3-%4/town_%5/development_%6? [R,L]
```

So what it is meant to do is:
user has been taken to:

http://www.domain.com/search/?propertytype=dev&bedrooms=2&minprice=0&maxprice=10000000&location=W1&development=W1

This page is the actual page on the server where the data is coming from, however I want the user to see.

http://www.domain.com/search/dev/2_bedrooms/price_0-10000000/town_W1/development_W1/

Is it possible to do this without a redirect loop.

Thanks for your help

**EDIT** I'm thinking it could be done with the rewrite flags but I'm not sure, I'm quite new to the Rewrite Engine

Comment: Can you alter the page that's sending the user to `http://www.domain.com/search/?propertytype=dev&bedrooms=2&minprice=0&maxprice=10000000&location=W1&development=W1` to instead send them to `http://www.domain.com/search/dev/2_bedrooms/price_0-10000000/town_W1/development_W1/` in the first place?

Comment: @wwarren I tried this before but didnt seem to get it to work, I thought I would put it on stackoverflow to see if anyone had a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699201/submitting-a-custom-query-string-from-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited*:

Here is a complete (and working) solution for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

# User gets here:
# http://localhost/search/?propertytype=dev&bedrooms=2&minprice=0&maxprice=10000000&location=W1&development=W1
# He is explicit redirected to here:
# http://localhost/search/dev/2_bedrooms/price_0-10000000/town_W1/development_W1/
# Internally, apache calls this:
# http://localhost/search.php?propertytype=dev&bedrooms=2&minprice=0&maxprice=10000000&location=W1&development=W1

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)_bedrooms/price_([^/]+)-([^/]+)/town_([^/]+)/development_([^/]+) search.php?propertytype=$1&bedrooms=$2&minprice=$3&maxprice=$4&location=$5&development=$6 [NC,PT]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} propertytype=([^/]+)&bedrooms=([^/]+)&minprice=([^/]+)&maxprice=([^/]+)&location=([^/]+)&development=([^/]+)
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ /search/%1/%2_bedrooms/price_%3-%4/town_%5/development_%6/? [R,L]
```

It assumes you put .htaccess in server root and that there is a file search.php in root too.

*Original:*

I think you can use `PT` and `QSA` Rewrite Rule flags (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html) in your first rule

Use `PT` for server-side redirection (it will not change the URL for the user/browser, but will for your server-side scripts)

Use `QSA` if you wanna carry the query while doing this redirection

You can redirect all requests that don't target an existing file to a specific php-script, for example:

> RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,QSA]

Comment: It still gives me a redirect loop!!