# Submitting a custom query string from form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form which at the moment when I submit it, it takes me to a url www.domain.com/search/?maxprice=10000000, however what I want it to do is to take me to a custom url e.g. www.domain.com/search/maxprice_10000000/

I found this javascript code which was meant to allow custom urls by stopping the form from doing its default action using `event.preventDefault()` However this either isnt working or isnt loading in the first place

Here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#propertysearch").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        window.location.href = "/"; //whatever i want but the problem is this doesnt seem to execute
    });
});
</script>
    <form id="propertysearch" action="/search" method="GET">

<p>
        <select id="maxprice" name="maxprice" style="width:47%;">
            <option value="10000000">Max Price...</option>
                <option disabled="disabled" value="10000000">- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -</option>
                <br />

<option value="100000">?100,000</option>
<option value="150000">?150,000</option>
<option value="200000">?200,000</option>
<option value="250000">?250,000</option>

        </select></p>

        <p><a href="javascript:document.forms['propertysearch'].submit();" title="Find a Property">Find a Property Now</a> &gt;</p>
        </form>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE** I have now got the code to work by using `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` instead of `<a href="javascript:document.forms['propertysearch'].submit();" title="Find a Property">Find a Property Now</a>`

so how can I change this my `<a></a>` to make it work

Thanks for your help

Comment: buddy, I have post the solution, but you didn't notice it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your example is using jQuery.  Either include jQuery, or go with a non-jQuery solution like so:

```
document.getElementById('propertytype').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    window.location.href = "/"; //whatever you want
});
```

Note that the above is not cross-browser compatible; you would have to also use `attachEvent`.

---

To use the `<a>`, I would just bind to the click event:

```
$("#propertysearch a").on('click', function (e) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //submission code
});

//pre jQuery 1.7
$("#propertysearch a").bind('click', function (e) {
```

Comment: I cant get this to work, its still just submitting a querystring, what do you mean I would have to use 'attachEvent'

Comment: @braza internet explorer uses `attachEvent`, but other browsers tend to use `addEventListener`.  Did you wrap this in `document.ready`?

Comment: my script code now looks like this :  `$(document).ready(function() {
   document.getElementById('propertysearch').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    window.location.href = "/map"; //whatever you want
});
});`

do I want to change this line `<form id="propertysearch" action="/about" method="GET">`?

Comment: @braza if you have access to jQuery you should use that.

Comment: Using my previous code I have added this `<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>`, is that all I need to make it work, because at the moment even with it, its still not working

Comment: I managed to get it to work with a submit button instead of my link, but how can I change it so I can still use my url, see UPDATE

Comment: I have post my solution, did you notice it?

Comment: I changed the code to `$("#propertysearch a").click(function (e) {` and it worked. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @braza remember to upvote and accept answers that help you.  `.on` was not introduced until jQuery 1.7, but that is a relatively old version.  If you are using a jQuery version that is more than a couple of versions back, you should specify

Comment: just realised, this only appears to be working in chrome, is there something i need to change to make it work in other browsers. Using `.on` and changed my jquery to 1.9.0

Comment: @braza should work just fine in other browsers; are you sure your JS is not cached?  Can you show me?

Comment: still only got chrome working. Just to check, I can include jquery like this `<script src="/includes/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` , and thats all I need for jquery?(assuming it is in that directory) and the `href` of my submit link should just be blank `href=""`?

Comment: just worked it out if you didnt enter anything in my form the value was "%" and if you try to go to that link you get a bad request from chrome, however ie just didnt do anything. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

delete the code: href="javascript:document.forms['propertysearch'].submit();" from you code, so it should be like this:`<p><a href='#' title="Find a Property">Find a Property Now</a></p>`